# Is there a PHP library or script that converts a UA to a human-friendly browser ID & version?

Tags: php, user-agent

Ideally, such a script would take a user agent (browser) string as input, like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)

and output:

> Firefox 3.6.13 (Windows XP)

or maybe:

```
array('os' => 'Windows XP', 'browser' => 'Firefox', version => '3.6.13')
```

Thoughts? Does this exist?

Comment: @DamienPirsy Was hoping someone had experience and a recommendation or code to share. I could implement this, and have before in other languages, but it is somewhat time-consuming and has lots of edge cases. Seems like a poster child for something to open-source.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getBrowser() 
{ 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. Thank you. I did have issues with the named groups in the regexes (we must be using different versions of PHP); using non-named groups fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), but read the note at the bottom: it is *your* responsibility to keep the browscap file up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). PHP documentation is a powerful tool!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is difficult enough as many web browsers exits and found that even the different version or different website browser represent the same User Agent String. Thus it makes it difficult to create a such thing. The list of User Agent can be found [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

But I found the very good [small program here](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/php_browser_detection.php). It really runs very fast and changes the User Agent String to as:

```
Your Computer Info
==================
Operating System:    Windows
NT 5.1 (Windows XP)
Current Browser / UA: Mozilla/ Firefox 19.0
ProductSub: 20100101
Layout Engine: Gecko
Engine Version: 19.0

HTML Support
HTML 5 Basic: Good
HTML 5 Forms: Good
XHTML: Yes

System Language    
Primary Language id: en-us
Primary Language: English (United States)
Current Screen Resolution: 1366 x 768 pixels
JavaScript: JavaScript is enabled.
Cookies: Cookies are enabled
PHP Browser Detection: Run Time: 0.00032091 Seconds
```

The above output is provided by script by small program it also detects maintains major list of mobile website browsers and robots which is amazing I have seen upto now.

Comment: Do you have an example of two browser versions with the same useragent string?  (The same version of IE with different service packs installed probably doesn't count.)